# How to upload an avatar image in a userSchema using multer.js and validating the fields before the upload

Tags: node.js, passport.js, multer

I am a beginner with node.js. I am building a simple application and I am trying to upload an avatar image in my userSchema using multer.js. To authenticate the user I use passport.js and I created a middleware that i want to use before uploading the image in the server and proceed with the registration of the user. The problem I think is that my validateRegister middleware block the request and I cannot let it proceed to the upload of the image and the registration of the user. If i move the upload before the validateRegister it works but i dont want upload any image before validation.

Please find code below:

models/User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
// const md5 = require('md5');
const validator = require('validator');
const mongodbErrorHandler = require('mongoose-mongodb-errors');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');


const userSchema = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please select if you are User or an Escort'
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true, 
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Invalid Email Address'],
        required: 'Please supply an email address'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Please supply a name',
        trim: true
    },
    photo: String,
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, { usernameField: 'email' });
userSchema.plugin(mongodbErrorHandler);


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

controllers/userController.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');
const multer = require('multer');
const jimp = require('jimp');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const multerOptions = {
    storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
    fileFilter: function(req, file, next) {
        const isPhoto = file.mimetype.startsWith('image/');
        if(isPhoto) {
            next(null, true);
        } else {
            next({message: 'The filetype is not allowed!'}, false);
        }
    }
};


exports.loginForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
}

exports.registerForm = (req, res) => {
    res.render('register', { title: 'Register' });
}

exports.upload = multer(multerOptions).single('photo');

exports.resize = async (req, res, next) => {
    // check if there is no new file to resize
    if (!req.file) {
        next();
        return;
    }
    const extension = req.file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
    req.body.photo = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`;
    // Resize
    const photo = await jimp.read(req.file.buffer);
    await photo.resize(800, jimp.AUTO);
    await photo.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body.photo}`);
    // once we have written the photo to the file system keep going
    next();
}

exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
    req.sanitizeBody('name');
    req.checkBody('type', 'You must supply a type, Please select if you are a user or an Superuser!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
    req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
        gmail_remove_dots: false,
        remove_extension: false,
        gmail_remove_subaddress: false
    });
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    const errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
        res.render('register', { title: 'Register', body: req.body, flashes: req.flash() });
        return;
    }
    next();
}

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = new User({ 
        email: req.body.email, 
        name: req.body.name,
        photo: req.body.photo,
        type: req.body.type
    });
    const register = promisify(User.register, User);
    await register(user, req.body.password);
    next();
};

exports.account = (req, res) => {
    res.render('account', { title: 'Edit your account' });
}

exports.updateAccount = async (req, res) => {
    const updates = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email
    };
  
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        { $set: updates },
        { new: true, runValidators: true, context: 'query' }
    );
    req.flash('success', 'Updated the profile!');
    res.redirect('back');
};
```

routes/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pageController = require('../controllers/pageController');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const { catchErrors } = require('../handlers/errorHandlers');


router.get('/', pageController.homePage);

// User Authentication
router.get('/login', userController.loginForm);
router.post('/login', authController.login);
router.get('/register', userController.registerForm);
router.post('/register',
  userController.upload, 
  catchErrors(userController.resize),   
  userController.validateRegister,
  userController.register,
  authController.login
);
router.get('/logout', authController.isLoggedIn, authController.logout);

router.get('/account', authController.isLoggedIn, userController.account);
router.post('/account', catchErrors(userController.updateAccount));

module.exports = router;
```

register.pug

```
form(action="/register" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data")
        h2 Register
        //- Category
        - const categories = ['user', 'escort' ]
        .mb-3 
            each category in categories 
                .form-check
                    input(type="radio" class="form-check-input" id=category value=category name="type")
                    label(for=category class="form-label") #{category} 
        //- Name
        .mb-3 
            label(for="name" class="form-label") Name 
            input(type="text" class="form-control" name="name")
        //- Email
        .mb-3 
            label(for="email" class="form-label") Email 
            input(type="email" class="form-control" name="email")
        //- Password
        .mb-3 
            label(for="password" class="form-label") Password 
            input(type="password" class="form-control" name="password")
        //- Confirm Password
        .mb-3 
            label(for="password-confirm" class="form-label") Confirm Password 
            input(type="password" class="form-control" name="password-confirm")
        //- Photo
        .mb-3 
            label(for="photo") Photo
            input(type="file" id="photo" class="form-control" name="photo" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg")
        input(type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary")
```

Thanj you very much in advance!